# Use of "¿A cómo está [...]?" to ask for a price

Tags: selección-de-palabras, preguntas, palabras-interrogativas

The *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* does not offer a suggestion regarding the use of [cómo](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=c%F3mo) to ask for the price of something (item, service, or currency). I am familiar with the variants *¿a cómo está/están ...?*, *¿a cómo es/son ...?*, and *¿a cómo ...?*. Google Books has examples of different ways of asking for the price of *a pound* (of a product or a type of currency):

- [¿A cómo es la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/S1KTh)
- [¿A cómo está la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/pzZUZ)
- [¿A cómo la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/n8jn7)
- [¿A cuánto está la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/GTTN4)

A [Dominican forum](http://www.dr1.com/forums/spanish-101/62141-como-son.html) seems to suggest a connection with the English *how much ... ?*. However, [English does not have a single-word equivalent for *cuánto*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/49546/1720) and therefore a quantity or amount is asked with *how much/many ...?*.

- Is it valid to use *¿a cómo ...?* (in any of its variants) to ask for the price of something?
- *¿A cuánto está ...?* seems like a more intuitive alternative. When is it preferable to use this form?
- Is there a relationship between the use of *¿a cómo ...?* in Spanish and the use of *how much/many ...?* in English?

---

El *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* no ofrece ninguna sugerencia acerca del uso de [cómo](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=c%F3mo) para preguntar el valor de algo (producto, servicio o moneda). Las variantes que conozco son *¿a cómo está/están ...?*, *¿a cómo es/son ...?* y *¿a cómo ...?*. Google Books contiene ejemplos de varias formas de preguntar el precio de *la libra* (de un producto o de alguna moneda como la libra esterlina):

- [¿A cómo es la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/S1KTh)
- [¿A cómo está la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/pzZUZ)
- [¿A cómo la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/n8jn7)
- [¿A cuánto está la libra ...?](http://goo.gl/GTTN4)

Un [foro dominicano en inglés](http://www.dr1.com/forums/spanish-101/62141-como-son.html) parece sugerir una conexión con el *how much ... ?* inglés. Sin embargo, [el inglés no posee una palabra equivalente a *cuánto*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/49546/1720) y por lo tanto una cantidad se pregunta con *how much/many ...?*.

- ¿Es válido el uso de *¿a cómo ...?* (en alguna de sus variantes) para preguntar el valor de algo?
- *¿A cuánto está ...?* es una alternativa más intuitiva, ¿cuándo es preferible el uso de ésta?
- Existe alguna relación entre el uso de *¿a cómo ...?* en español con el uso de *how much/many ...?* en inglés?

Comment: "A cuánto está el cambio para comprar libras?", "Cuál es el precio de venta para la libra?" or more technical:"Cuál es el tipo de cambio para la libra?". "A cómo ..." is used in some places, but I always thought of it as a "localismo".

Comment: No olvidemos que el uso de la forma ¿A cómo/cuanto está ... no sólo se utiliza en ese ambito de negocios sino que es MUY usado en el mercado y coloquialmente para preguntar precios ¿A cuánto están los tomates hoy? Esto puede orientar un poco la respuesta.

Comment: _¿A cómo ...?_ es lo suficientemente común para merecer una opinión oficial a favor o en contra de su uso. Me parece extraño que la versión virtual del [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/) no mencione esta frase en su artículo acerca de [cómo](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=c%F3mo).

Comment: _¿A cómo ...?_ pareciera relacionarse con el _At what price is/are ...?_ del inglés.

Comment: Aunque encontré la respuesta, el _bounty_ de +50 sigue en pie para aquel que encuentre alguna otra referencia diferente a la _Nueva gramática de la lengua española_ (2009).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tras una ardua búsqueda, encontré que la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* (2009) explica que el uso de *a cómo* es aceptable para preguntar el precio o valor de algo (el énfasis en negrita es propio):

> **22.16j** Se usa el adverbio exclamativo *cómo* en su interpretación cuantitativa con varios predicados que tienen argumentos de esa misma naturaleza: el ya citado *tardar*, así como *demorarse*, *durar* o *pesar*, entre otros. El verbo *costar* admite también esta alternancia cuando se refiere al hecho de resultar penosa alguna tarea: *Habrá que hinchar la fe para reconstruir el futuro. Pero cómo cuesta* (*Salvador Hoy* 15/11/2000).
>   No la admite, en cambio, cuando denota la propiedad de tener algo determinado valor o precio: *¡{Cuánto*~Cómo} cuesta hoy un kilo de manzanas!* Cabría pensar que esta asimetría se relaciona con la naturaleza pronominal de *cuánto* en estos últimos contextos, ya que se pregunta en ellos por ciertas unidades de medida. **En general, no se extiende a *cómo* la interpretación pronominal de *cuánto*. Se rechaza, por consiguiente, la equivalencia entre ambos adverbios en *Hay que ver cuánto logró recorrer sin detenerse*, donde *cuánto* significa ´cuánta distancia, cuánto trecho´. Se exceptúan las contrucciones formadas con la pauta «*a* + *cómo* cuantitativo» características de los verbos *costar*, *vender*, *salir*, etc., cuyos complementos denotan precio. Estas construcciones, en las que alternan *cómo* y *cuánto*, son también peculiares por que admiten la interpretación cuantitativa de *cómo* en contextos interrogativos**:
>   Trataba [...] de preguntar para qué servía esto y aquello y lo de más allá, y cuánto costaba y *a cómo* se vendía (Pardo Bazán, *Pazos*); Diga usté [sic] *a cómo* la paga, respondió don Pioquinto (Buitrago, J., *Pescadores*); ¿*A cómo* estaba el dólar en el peor momento de la crisis de diciembre de 1994 y enero de 1995? (*Excélsior* 1/11/1996); ¿*A cómo* las naranjas? (Cardoza, *Guatemala*); ¿*A cómo* se cotizan? (Moreno-Durán, *Diana*); ¿*A cómo* amanecería esta mañana nuestro pesito de hojalata, mis valedores? (Mojarro, *Yo*); ¿*A cómo* está frente al dólar? (Quesada, *Banana*).

Real Academia Española y Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Espanola. [Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://books.google.com/books?id=OCwqAQAAIAAJ). Volumen 1. Espasa Calpe. 2009. pág. 1659.

Comment: También explica de que a cuál es equivalente y que no hay ninguna preferencia... pues ambos son casos peculiares

Answer (score 4):

So I will address your questions one by one:

> ¿Es válido el uso de ¿a cómo ...? (en alguna de sus variantes) para preguntar el valor de algo?

It is valid asking in any of the forms you provided.

> ¿A cuánto está ...? es una alternativa más intuitiva, ¿cuándo es preferible el uso de ésta?

I am not sure why do you qualify this alternative as more intuitive as for me it is the same. Maybe from a language learning point of view?

There is no preferred case as when to use ¿A cuánto está? rather than ¿A cómo está?, because in practice they mean exactly the same and their use are so widespread that there is no widely recognized preference for one or the other.

> Existe alguna relación entre el uso de ¿a cómo ...? en español con el uso de how much/many ...? en inglés?

No there is no relationship between them opposed to ¿A cuánto...? in Spanish. Languages don't always have exact equivalents for everything and this is one of those things that can't be exactly translated. This happens for example very often with german that is a language with words that are very specific to a context. It is bound to happen because each language has its own flow and context.

There are some alternatives as to asking a price or value of something in spanish:

> ¿Cuánto vale xxxxx?
>
> ¿A cuánto es (article, e.g. el/la etc..) xxxxx?
>
> ¿A cómo (article, e.g. el/la etc..) xxxxx?

Note: there is NO reference in the RAE (and consequently we can presume on the other spanish academies that are aligned to the RAE) about the preference between the two cases or on how to ask the question properly or if there are any rules related to it.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas más variantes: en España *no* es habitual `¿A cómo está?` o `¿A cuánto está?`, sino más bien `¿Cuánto cuesta?` o `¿Qué vale?`, que viene a ser nuestro `How much is it?`.

Comment: En respuesta a @Juanga Covas, pásate por el sur de España y verás que es muy, muy habitual decir "¿a cómo están las fresas?" o "¿a cuánto están las fresas?". Es decir, en español del mismo centro de Valladolid, lo mismo no es habitual pero, ¡ay, amigo! muchas variantes tiene el español. :)

Comment: Toda la razón, generalicé demasiado ;)

Answer (score 2):

Al menos en la Ciudad de México, lo más habitual es preguntar:

> ¿Cuánto cuesta *[un producto o servicio]*?
>
> ¿En cuánto está el/la *[una moneda extranjera (para preguntar por el tipo de cambio)]*?

También, muchas personas preguntan, cuando quieren saber el precio actual de algunos productos, por ejemplo los relacionados con los alimentos:

> ¿Cuánto vale *[un producto (por ejemplo "el plátano")*?

Answer (score 2):

Argentina:

> "¿Cuánto cuesta ...?"  "¿Cuánto vale ...?"  "¿A cuánto está...?"

son las formas más usadas.  También "¿Cuánto sale...?" (para bienes pequeños, compras cotidianas), "¿Qué precio tiene?", o (raramente) "¿Qué vale...".

"¿A cómo ...?" no se usa por aquí, pero se entiende.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Es válido el uso de ¿a cómo ...? (en alguna de sus variantes) para
>   preguntar el valor de algo?

Sí, pero cuando hablamos de español, toma en cuenta que cada país que lo habla tiene sus variantes. Lo ideal es no apegarse a los detalles locales para tener un español más universal y entendible por todos.

Por experiencia personal, 'a cómo' suele ser dicho ya sea predominantemente en españa o bien, por la clase baja en latinoamerica. Es una forma burda de preguntar dado que cómo (how) no es específico de cantidad. El equivalente en inglés sería algo tipo... 'So how's the british pound?'. Indudablemente generaría confusión. Usar 'cuánto' es la manera correcta dado que específica 'cantidad'.

> ¿A cuánto está ...? es una alternativa más intuitiva, ¿cuándo es
>   preferible el uso de ésta?

Sí, de todas las opciones que enlistaste, es la más 'coloquial' e intuitiva. Para terminar la oración sin embargo, pondría algo así:

¿A cuánto está la libra esterlina? | ¿A cuánto está la libra en pesos? etc...

> Existe alguna relación entre el uso de ¿a cómo ...? en español con el
>   uso de how much/many ...? en inglés?

Hasta donde se, 'a como' es un ejemplo del mal uso del lenguaje dado que no 'como' no está directamente relacionado a cantidades. Cómo = how, pero sin 'much' detrás.

A cómo NO ES equivalente a HOW MUCH en el sentido estricto de la palabra, solo en el entendimiento coloquial.

Si lo hicieramos en inglés, sería lo mismo, no puedes ir a una tienda y decir:

How's the coke bottle?
So how's the bag of chips?

No hay nada haciendo referencia a CANTIDAD